# How to generically recursively reverse any array? (Without using C++ Standard Library)

Tags: c++, recursion

**How to reverse any data type array recursively having the array and its size?**

Like:

```
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
So that int array[] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}

OR

std::string array[] = {"ab", "aaa", "xxx", "ddd"};
So that it becomes std::string array[] = {"ddd","xxx","aaa","ab"}
```

The reason for not using the **C++ Standard Library** is so that the problem isn't simply solved for you, where you include one library, invoke one line and that solves the problem.

The point of this question was to solve the problem in a different way, so one can get  better comprehension and grasp of other language tools and programming concepts.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> 
void swap(T& t1, T& t2) {
   T tmp(t1);
   t1=t2; 
   t2=tmp;  
}  

template<typename T> void 
reverse(T* first, T* last) {// Array of type T, indistinct type

    if(first < last)
    {
        swap(*first, *last);
        reverse(first+1, last-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to implement an algorithm, just go to [the page that describes the function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).  The 'non-STL" implementation is right there.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie For some reason OP wants to use recursion for this...

Comment: The STL is not good enough, a non-STL implementation is not good enough -- how far do we take this?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's not about the STL. The STL is great. This is about how you can do things without the STL. The STL is C++ Standard Library and it has thousands of useful containers, data structures and functions. Sometimes, people want to know how things work behind the scenes. Is it that punishable and hard to understand?

Comment: @SantiagoVarela The link I gave you shows the "non-STL" implementation.  Did you not see it?

Comment: Just by the way, a recursive reverse is going to be silly no matter what. It's not a good use of recursion; STL implementation probably uses a loop. (I didn't downvote the question.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, do you not read? The possible implementation there uses std::iter_swap to do std::reverse...

Comment: And what do you think `iter_swap` does?  Seriously, that is enough for a downvote for "lack of research".

Comment: Why can't you use `std::reverse`? I think it might help if you explain why you can't use it.

Comment: One problem is that questions along the lines of "I need to do X, how do I do it" are too broad for SO. In your case it's "I have an array, how do I sort it". Well there are plenty of ways to sort it and you've provided only one. Your answer isn't much better as it's just a basic code dump without a lot of background or context.

Comment: And what is wrong with showing an implementation that is already there?  I could have shown no links, copied and pasted the answers from those links below with a couple of revisions, and that would have been better?  Also, there are literally thousands of sites showing reversal using arrays and recursion.  One reason for downvote is "lack of research".

Comment: If you don't want to use stuff in the STL you can always just use `std::reverse`.

Comment: _Another_ edit? Well I guess if you don't want to use stuff in the C++ standard library you can always use an implementation of the STL.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious ISO 14882 C++ Standard never refers to STL, but the C++ Standard Library. STL was written independently and some elements of STL made it to the Standard Library. std::reverse is not part of STL.

Comment: Part of my job is hiring programmers. The quality of the education they get is very important. I don't want easy-solve answers just floating around on the internet because that means I have to weed good programmers from good googlers, and that wastes my time. If I get fooled and hire one, that's wasted time for me and my co-workers because we have to make up for being a person down and clean up the messes left before the bad programmer is moved on.

Comment: One thing that has me stumped is where are all the duplicates? I know I've seen this question before. I've answered it at least once. I can find dupes for most of the other popular languages here, but not for C or C++. Did they all get hoovered?

Comment: Your `swap` function is worse than `std::swap` for types where moving is better than copying.

Comment: @user54264611634646244 I'm aware of the history of the STL and it's relation to the C++ Standard but thanks for the remedial lesson. There are STL's that include an implementation of `reverse` as described in the C++ Standard. Some even have an option of being appearing in the `std` namespace. It might not exist in the crappy implementation your'e using but it's out there.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <algorithm>

    std::reverse( std::begin(array), std::end(array) );
```

Works regardless of the type of element.

Answer (score -2):

I don't get what you mean with recursion in this case.
Anyway, I'll explain how I did it, through the solution for your first example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
       int temp;
       temp = array[i];
       array[i] = array[8-i];
       array[8-i] = temp;
   }
```

First you must know how many elements your array has, then if this number is even you can cycle the `for` above until `i < n/2`, if it's odd until the half of the lowest and closest even number (here you had 9 elements, then 8/2 = 4), since the number in the middle of the array would be swapped with itself.

The `for` cycle is swapping the elements through a temporary object (`temp`), used for "storage": imagine `array[i]`, `temp` and `array[8-i]` as boxes, and you opening the first and copying into it the elements of the second etc as in the code.

The even case:

```
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

   for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
       int temp;
       temp = array[i];
       array[i] = array[9-i];
       array[9-i] = temp;
   }
```

Anyway, try learning how to use the STL wherever you can, like aschepler suggested you, you can Google why.

Comment: Can I ask why the downvotes?

Comment: Not a good answer. For example, the first block of code should be part of a function - show the function. And in C++ we always want to initialise things, rather than use assignment.  Similarly in the second block of code.

Comment: Ok, I thought about the initialization thing, but knew that at least numerical types were initialized by default, like int to zero. And in my opinion a downvote may lead to think of a wrong answer. Anyway, free to vote as you wish, and I'm here to learn. Thank you!

Comment: " but knew that at least numerical types were initialized by default, like int to zero" Like, they are not.

Comment: Nice, good to know!

Comment: How is this recursive?

Comment: I wrote it is not, at the beginning. Sorry, it was my first answer and thought it could be helpful, but I understand the answer must be 100% coherent with the query and not just focused in solving the issue, or better not to poste any answer at all. My fault.